# Display facebook live streamed video in my iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm integrating facebook live video streaming in my iOS application. 
Live streaming is happening in my facebook page and I want to play that video in my iOS app. 
How I can play it in my iOS app.?
I'm getting video id and data through graph api. But I don't know how to play this in my app. Can anyone help me?

```
 {
      "description": "Test",
      "embed_html": "<iframe src=\"https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2F781315052033054%2Fvideos%2F791075327723693%2F&width=1280\" width=\"1280\" height=\"720\" style=\"border:none;overflow:hidden\" scrolling=\"no\" frameborder=\"0\" allowTransparency=\"true\" allowFullScreen=\"true\"></iframe>",
      "updated_time": "2017-03-14T09:51:36+0000",
      "live_status": "LIVE",
      "id": "791075327723693"
}
```

Comment: Simple solution, put that `iframe` in to a WebView :)

Comment: Yes I tried that also, but I can't play it in WebView. It gives me error to "Get Facebook App". While it is working in browser.

Comment: @SandeepGangajaliya did you figure out how to play it in iOS app with WKWebView? Same issue here, I can play it in regular browser but it says that video unavailable when I open it in WKWebKit

Comment: Hi Sandeep, could you please tell me how you got the stream URL from Facebook?

Answer (score 2):

this one is from facebook Docs..

Live on Mobile
I am trying to watch a live video on mobile web, but it's not showing up? Is this a bug?
No, this is the expected behavior as we do not currently support watching live videos on mobile web until they are VODs (Videos On Demand). However, if you want to watch a live video on mobile web that has been embedded into another site, it will be redirected to the Facebook app to watch.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a video player to play the facebook video in your app then don't use "embedded_html", instead, you should use the "dash_preview_url" of the video.